# Laravel Not found after pulling from github

Tags: apache, github, laravel-5, wampserver

hi after **pulling** my **laravel application** from **github** into **apache** (**wampserver**)and executing `composer update` everytime i try to acces to one of my route  it shows me

**Not Found
The requested URL /getud/public/mat was not found on this server.**

How could i fix this problem thnks
[image]

Comment: Seems like public (root) directory has wrong settings

Comment: Can you past a screenshot of the error.

Comment: how could i fix public settings ?

Comment: the only error that i get is Not Found

The requested URL /getud/public/mat was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win32) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80

Comment: [The need for Virtual Hosts to make applications run correctly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618)